# How do you convert mongod to mongo service?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been running MongoDB on two Windows 10 PCs.  However, one has mongo always running it seems where I only need to open command prompt and type **mongo**.  This gives me access to the db on PC #1.

However, on PC #2, I must open command prompt and type **mongod**.  Then I have to open a second command prompt to type in *mongo*, then I get access to the db on PC #2.

After doing this for about a year, I find I want to just want both PCs to work like PC #1, where I just type in *mongo* and not *mongodb* and only have to use one command prompt.

I checked online but there's nothing I found straightforward to accomplish this specifically.

Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: Follow step-by-step installation guide https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-mongodb-community-edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in PC#2, your **MongoDB** version is **< 4.0**, then you can't do anything i.e., you have to continue with `mongod` to start **Mongo** as you do now.
But if your **MongoDB** version is **>= 4.0** or you want to upgrade from lower version of **MongoDB**, you can follow the below steps.

1. Take backup of all databases with `mongodump`. If it is large volume data, then go through [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/).
2. Uninstall your **MongoDB** using Windows Uninstall Program features.
3. Reinstall MongoDB using the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-mongodb-community-edition).
4. While installing, ensure you select '**MongoDB Service**' feature.
5. Start the MongoDB now in PC#2 as you do in PC#1.
6. Restore the old databases with `mongorestore`.